# Angular Observable not updating when I subscribe.

Tags: angular, observable

My main goal here is to have a service that owns a map and returns an observable. I'd like to intercept the update of that observable and convert the data to a string that I display in the UI. I do this sort of thing elsewhere but it doesn't seem to like working with maps, I'm not exactly sure what is going on. 
The service is similar to:

```
MyService {
    myMap: {[index:string]: string};

    add(key:string, value:string) {
        this.map[key] = value;
    }

    remove(key:string) {
        delete this.map[key];
    }

    getMap() Observable<{[index:string]: string}> {
        return Observable.of(this.map);
    }
}
```

And then in my component I have tried several things but can't seem to accomplish what I want. My goal is to take any updates to the map and convert them to a string and update my UI So I have tried something like:

```
MyComponent {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.getMap().subscribe((update) => {
            // I would think I would consistently get updated here but this 
            // only hits once. At this point update would be the map and I 
            // would process the data into the string I want to display in the 
            // UI
        });
    }
}
```

Not really sure where to go. I do this sort of thing with arrays all the time and the 
    something | async
technique but am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `Observable.of` is not the way to go. It will emit the map once and then emit complete event. I would suggest using `BehaviorSubject` instead, and keep it synced manually:

```
MyService {
  myMap: {[index:string]: string};
  myMap$ = new BehaviorSubject<{[index:string]: string}>(this.myMap);

  add(key:string, value:string) {
    this.map[key] = value;
    this.myMap$.next(this.map);
  }

  remove(key:string) {
    delete this.map[key];
    this.myMap$.next(this.map);
  }

  getMap() Observable<{[index:string]: string}> {
    return this.myMap$;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Subject` to send stuff to the `Observable`. Like so:

```
MyService {
    mapSource = new Subject()<{[index:string]: string}>();

    myMap: {[index:string]: string};

    add(key:string, value:string) {
        this.map[key] = value;
        this.mapSource.next(this.map);
    }

    remove(key:string) {
        delete this.map[key];
        this.mapSource.next(this.map);
    }

    getMap() Observable<{[index:string]: string}> {
        return this.mapSource.asObservable();
    }
}
```